# Attach the contents of a list or a for loop in the body of an email

Tags: python

So I am playing around with the reddit api, and for this exercise I just want a simple script that gathers the top 10 posts on certain sub, posts and puts the title and the urls in an email. Just that. But I can't for some reason append the results of the `for` loop in the body of the email

I currently store the values of the 10 hot posts and their links in a list called "posts".

```py
import praw
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="ID",
    client_secret="ID",
    username="username",
    password="password",
    user_agent="agent",
)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("worldnews")

hot_worldnews = subreddit.hot(limit=10)

posts = []

for post in hot_worldnews:
    posts.append(post.title + "\n" + post.url + "\n")


# Once I have that, I compile the email:


message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "Today's headlines"
message["From"] = "News bot"
recipients = ["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com"]
message["To"] = ""
message["bcc"] = " ,".join(recipients)

# creating the content of the email, first the plain content then the html content

plain = """
Today's headlines:
""" + "\n".join(
    posts
)

html = """
<h1><span style="color: #ff0000; background-color: #000000;"><strong>Today's headlines!</strong></span></h1>
""" + "\n".join(
    posts
)

# now we compile both parts to prepare them to send

part1 = MIMEText(plain, "plain")
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
message.attach(part1)
message.attach(part2)

# Now send the email

gmail_user = "user"
gmail_pwd = "pass"
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
server.sendmail(message["From"], recipients, message.as_string())
```

and it kind of sends me the headlines and the links but all together.

I have been digging here for different solutions and well, it's clear that I cannot include a for loop in the body of an email, but the `'\n'.join(posts)` formula doesn't seem to work either because all the posts come one after the other but I can't format it properly. The output email is a jumble of text and links

Any insight?

Comment: Have you tried using `\r\n`?

Comment: Oh, in HTML view you should probably use `<\br>` instead of `\n` as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML mail, you'll want to join the strings with the HTML line break `<br>` instead, since a `\n` newline is rendered as a space in HTML.

I've added the `\n` too to make debugging easier, but as said, it will be basically ignored by your browser/mail client. (I also optimized the HTML style a little :-) )

```py
plain = """
Today's headlines:
""" + '\n'.join(posts)

html = """
<h1 style="color: #f00; background: #000; font-weight: bold">Today's headlines!</h1>
""" + '<br />\n'.join(posts)
```

Comment: Ok that shows the headlines and the links side by side, so it works. So if now I wanted to add a line break between the headline and the link? if you see this piece of code:
` for post in hot_worldnews:
    posts.append(post.title + "\n" + post.url + "\n") `

you'll see that I create this in a way of being 2 lines per headline+link...

Answer (score 0):

ok, so no that worked, but now let's say I want to do it this other way, attaching this piece of hmtml code to my email:

```
<h1>Today's headlines:</h1>
<p>{}</p>
<hr />
<p>The weather is going to be {} in {} with a max temperature of {}</p>
<hr />
<p>&nbsp;</p>.format(posts, weather, location, temp)
```

What I am trying to do now is: I have a big block of html with a lot of '{}' (I'm sorry I don't know how to call them properly). After the html I can call them all one by one. The problem is in the previous exercise I could do it just adding '+' to the last html line and include `'<br />\n'.join(posts)` and it will just work. But in this other example I cannot do that.

What would be the way of doing this now in this instance? I have tried replacing `'<br />\n'.join(posts)` with a variable but obviously it doesn't work.

Hope I have explained myself properly.

Comment: You can construct the HTML markup piece by piece, of course, but as things get more complicated, you might want to look into a templating language – Jinja2 is pretty great. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/

Comment: I refactored things a little to add Jinja2 so you can see the gist of how it'd work. Hope it helps. https://gist.github.com/akx/7f654c7c6e7c8fa8ab023a1806c37f72

Comment: that looks great actually! I'll have a look into it!